# og:image URL error: https://mydomain/session/upload/undefined could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, next.js, socialshare

Here I used to debug the above URL using Facebook sharing debugger. I have this message after debugged.

> Invalid Image Content Provided og:image URL, https://mydomain/session/upload/undefined could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.

I have used Next.js, and my head tag include:

```
<meta
    property="og:image"
    content={`${apiUrl}/session/upload/${session?.image}`}
/>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The fact that it's complaining about `https://mydomain/session/upload/undefined` means that `session?.image` is returning `undefined` in your code. Ensure that `session.image` is always set, or provide a different image URL when it's not.

Comment: This image is dynamically loaded via an API call, and I think the head tag is rendered before the API call. that's why this image returning undefined but I'm not sure what nextjs functions are being used to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The image path is "..../undefined", that image most likely does not exist.

Make sure `${session?.image}` is not undefined. You could also use a fallback image in case it is not defined, for example:

```
<meta
    property="og:image"
    content={session?.image ? `${apiUrl}/session/upload/${session.image}` : 'fallback-image-url'}
/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the image is defined. still, didn't work

Comment: what is the exact url of the image in the page source?

Comment: session sounds like a session. Facebook will do a separate request which will most likely be a different session.

Comment: @luschn exact url - http://mydomain/session/upload/undefined and correct URL should be  http://mydomain/session/upload/a7be87f2b811.jpg

Comment: exactly, it is "undefined", as i though